# How to access Azure storage account Via Azure Key Vault by service principal

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-keyvault

I have an external web application which has the option to access a storage account using the service principal.

I want to access Azure storage account/blob by the external application loading the data directly into the datalake account.

So here is what I am trying to do:

- Set up a service principal (using Azure AD app registration)
- Create a Storage account and store the access key in Azure Key Vault.
- Add the service principal secret to the same key vault.
- Create a policy within Key vault for the service principal to have access to read Keys and Secrets within Key Vault.
- Also create a policy within Key Vault for service principal to have contributor role to access storage account.
- Also grant access to storage account container to service principal.

But I cannot connect, and I am unable to authorize the connection.

I am confused on which steps I am missing to resolve this.

Comment: Is your External Web Application (I'm assuming you are talking about an App Service here) running under a managed identity or using the service principal?

Comment: From what I understand, you want your external application to fetch the storage access key from your key vault. What secret is your application using to access the key vault? For this you would have to share the secret with the application.  And if you're doing this, you might as well share the secret and grant the service principal access directly to the storage acct. There is no need for key vault here. If your application is hosted under the same azure tenant as your storage acct then that's a different story.

Comment: @kane application is 'Adverity' which as option to configure destination as Azure blob with Service principle.

Comment: @AnupamChand My application is SAS product 'Adverity' who want to load the data to Azure blob, which means its NOT hosted on same Azure tenant. So if this is true then , I already have give role for service principle to to read/write to storage account... So, their a not need to store storage access key in key vault and then have service principle reading from their ?

Comment: Then they should store the service principal secret in their application and use it to access the storage account directly. No need to key vault it. They will need to use the secret to fetch the bearer token from your AAD and then access the storage account.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to access the storage account using service principal, you do not need to store the storage account access in the key vault.

The steps you can follow up to access storage account by service principal:

1. Create a service principal (Azure AD App Registration)
2. Create a storage account
3. Assign Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the service principal

Now you would be able to access the Azure Storage Blob data using your service principal

**Note**: You do not need to store the service principal client secret in the key vault. Because you need the client secret again to access the key vault first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @RamaraoAdapa-MT
This works

Finally, I setup like you said,,
SAS -> service principle -> permission to storage account -> storage account.

In this case, no need for Key vault.

Thanks you Guys,
Anupam Chand, RamaraoAdapa-MT